# Transferring String from UIViewController using Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am doing the following:

```
#ViewController1.m

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"Transferring");

   guestViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
   [controller.label isEqualToString:self.num_value.text];
}
```

However when the view is loaded, the text does not run through or show up in the label. I have done this in past programs and it has worked on Xcode 4. However, for some reason in Xcode 5 it is not working for me. Is there something else that I need to implement to make this work in Xcode?

Comment: With `[controller.string isEqualToString:self.num_value.text];` you're only comparing the two strings, you're not assigning anything to anything

Comment: @micantox so you recommend that I change it to "controller.label.text = self.num_value.text"?

Comment: YES! `isEqualToString` is for comparison! Not to assign a value!

Comment: wait, no you cannot assign the text to a label before the view is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `guestViewController`'s header file :

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;`

The your `prepareForSegue` method becomes something like this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"Transferring");

   guestViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
   [controller setValue : self.num_value.txt];
}
```

`isEqualToString` is for comparison! Not to be used for assigning values.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` method, add this :

`[textLabel setText : value];`

Comment: So the value of the label can only be transferred to view controllers through strings? I can't transfer the value from label to label?

Comment: You can. You see its the property type that matters. You can declare a UILabel property in the guestViewController. Then you can say `[controller setLabel : self.myLabel]`

Comment: @Zack - Did I answer your question ?

Comment: Yes you did but lemme try it on computer before selecting as the correct answer!

Comment: Label still does not change text value even after [controller setLabel: self.myLabel]

Comment: are you sure you've connected your label to that in the view ?

Comment: Instead of UILabel - try the conventional approach of transferring the NSString and then using that to set the text of your label in the `guestViewController`.

Comment: Yes it is connected. In "setLabel" the "Label" part is the identifier I gave the label in guestViewController correct? So if the uilabel was bob I would type [controller setBob: ] right?

Comment: Yes. But try passing a NSString value, not UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

```
[controller.string isEqualToString:self.num_value.text];
```

`isEquelToString` only check is `controler.string` is the same or not as `self.num.value.text.`

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string is equal
>   to the receiver using a literal Unicode-based comparison.

Read the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

your can pass your string to the another controller like this:

In `guestViewController's` h file :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theStringWhatYouWantToGet;
```

and in `prepareForSegue`:

```
controller.theStringWhatYouWantToGet  = self.num_value.text;
```